# Replacement of DBA_Source in Postgres to find DB objects

Tags: postgresql

How can I know table (table_1) is being used in which all UDF?

Below query gives me table's details:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables;
```

Below Query gives UDF details:

```
select * FROM pg_proc;
```

But how can I know that table1 is used in which all UDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string search in the `prosrc` column of `pg_proc` is the only way if you want to find dependencies between functions and tables.

Of course that is not very satisfying, because it would be rather difficult to say if – say – an occurrence of `table_1` is a reference to the table or a variable name. Also, you cannot find the source of C functions in the catalog.

To get a reliable answer, you would need insight into the language in which the function is written, and here is the core of the problem: PostgreSQL does *not* have any insight into the language! PostgreSQL's fabled extensibility allows you to define new languages for functions, and only the *language handler* knows how to interpret the string that is the function body. That also holds for PL/pgSQL which is shipped with PostgreSQL.

That is also the reason why there are no `pg_depend` entries for objects used in functions.